# Trie dictionary lookups

Tags: javascript, dictionary, trie

just read http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-trie-performance-analysis/

i have the dictionary of users names and surnames

```
Alex Woha
Mike Ivanov 
Donald Duck
Alex Wolf
John Wolf
```

and so on. Suppose user entered word

```
Wolf
```

I have to suggest him the next

```
Alex Wolf
John Wolf
```

If he entered

```
Wolf Al or Alex Wol
```

I have to suggest only

```
Alex Wolf
```

The dictionary is large, so i would prefer to use trie or dawg. How can i solve this problem?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it seems you're expecting people to write code for you. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help writing questions that will attract good answers. If you are just needing a starting point, try Googling "How to code a trie in javascript", for which this [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/25359/simple-trie-implementation-in-javascript) SE question comes up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, i solve this problem by using ngram index (here is my [implementation](https://github.com/alldroll/suggest))

Answer (score 0):

what you're looking for is a prefix based trie. not all trie implementations do that (john resig's implementation is one of those).
fortunately, node natural's trie implemenation does. from the documentation:

> Tries are a very efficient data structure used for prefix-based searches. Natural comes packaged with a basic Trie implementation which can support match collection along a path, existence search and **prefix search**.

check it out here https://github.com/NaturalNode/natural#tries